# How to use chrome.proxy.settings.set() in Manifest V3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the given manifest v2 code  "chrome.proxy.settings.set" is used. will it work in manifest v3 also? if not, how to modify this code so that it works on v3?

```
    const setProxySettings = (config) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.proxy.settings.set(
          {
            value: config,
            scope: "regular",
          },
        

  () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Try it first and describe the problem if it exists in more detail.